# In Laravel 5.5, an AJAX post request redirects when not

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am doing just basic subscribe form, trying to use Ajax post request.
Since I am new to Ajax I googled some about this issue but no success, even though it is an easy fix probably.

The issue is, that when I submit form, it will throw me error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

**View.blade:**

```
//Ajax

<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $("#subscribeform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var emailval = $('#subscriber').val();
        console.log(emailval);
        if(emailval !== "") {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '/subscribing',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    email:emailval
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>

//Form
<form id="subscribeform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="subscriber" id="subscriber" placeholder=" email@example.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/subscribing', 'SubsController@store');
```

**Controller**

```
class SubsController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $newsubscriber = new Subscriber;
        $newsubscriber->email = $request->input('email');
        $newsubscriber->save();
    }

}
```

Namespacing is good I am sure, so what could be an issue really?

Comment: Try replacing `url: '/subscribing'` with `url: '{{ action("SubsController@store") }}'`

Comment: MethodnotAllowedExpection is thrown when you try to request the route with different type that is being defined in routes . So my guess would be ajax may have been requesting through get Method . Can you share the network detail of request from google chrome's Developer panel

Answer (score 0):

Change "type" to "method".

You are also forgetting the CSRF token in your AJAX call. Add it as a parameter :

```
_token : {{ csrf_token() }}
```

Blade will insert it into your js.

Comment: @OndOne, did you try adding in this parameter into the data sent?

Comment: `type` and `method` are the same when it comes to jquery ajax, `type` is an aliased version of `method`.

Answer (score 0):

According to above answers i think it is because of `csrf_token`, to solve your problem try like this,

You need to use `ajaxSetup` as recommended in the docs like below,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

and also add this on your template,

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Or alternatively just add this to your form,

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

For more details read [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf).

Comment: I did exactly as everything here is said, still nothing. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your `SubsController.php`

```
use App\Subscriber;
```

Ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

$("#subscribeform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var emailval = $('#subscriber').val();
        console.log(emailval);
        if(emailval !== "") {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '/subscribing',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                     _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}',
                    email:emailval
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Model `Subscriber.php'

```
  class Subscriber extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['email'];
     protected $table = 'subscriber';

}
```

And add following code to your header:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [Jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the key for request method in ajax settings is "method", not "type", which means Your request is GET by default. Therefore Method is not allowed, as stated in exception.

Comment: Thank you.Anyway i changed that to method and still the same, any ideas? :[

Comment: Well, I would make sure that a POST request is really sent to the correct route. Check that specific request in DevTools Network tab, maybe You'll notice something there?

As a side note, I would not look for crsf token-related things (as suggested by others), as it would throw TokenMismatchException, not MethodNotAllowed.

Comment: @StevenmcKevin This is not the case, you can use `type` to set the request type, it is documented on the docs page as an alias of the `method` setting.